# genuine way to give an image an emphasized and normal caption

Tags: floats, subcaption, emphasis

In my work I give each image a small description (usually in emphasized style) and a long description in normal font. To achieve this I have to write

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{elephant}
    \subcaption{\emph{An Elephant}. This is an Elephas maximus, bla bla bla}
    \label{fig:elephant}
\end{figure}
```

I am tired of always writing `\emph{…}.` Is there a command to shorten this? E.g.

```
\subcaptionhead{An Elephant}{This is an Elephas maximus, bla bla bla}
```

(All images should still be in `\listoffigures`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newcommand\shead[2]{\subcaption{\emph{#1}#2}}
```

And usage:

```
\shead{An Elephant}{This is an Elephas maximus, bla bla bla}
```

Comment: One shouldn't use `\def` anymore, but rather `\newcommand`
See [l2tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu)

Comment: thank you, I just posted this one too. However there is still an issue concerning the listoffigures

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found one way to easily solve this:

```
\newcommand{\scaption}[2]{\subcaption{\emph{#1}. #2}
```

This seems to work fine with the `\listoffigures`-page. However, I did not achieve to let subfloats appear within the listing (using the `subfloat`-package).